# select same columns twice in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Have a select Statement like

```
select 
SouceField_A  
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter'
+ SouceField_A
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter'
+ SourceField_B
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter'
...
```

Problem is that in real life I do not have a simple Field, but have CASE WHEN ... END. This makes it error prone and difficult to Keep both places up to date when Change is required.
For this I wonder if there is an easy way to put it into variable etc.

Below is part of query to Show

```
select 
ISNULL ( Oracle_Update , 'create' )  + '~' +
@Email + '~' +
@ItemNo + '~' +
''  + '~' +
'D'  + '~' +
ISNULL ( Item_Desc_DE , '' )  + '~' +
REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL ( Item_Specification_DE , '' ), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR   (10), ' $#') + '~' +    
ISNULL ( Item_Copy_From, '' ) + '~' +
 -- master template
 CASE WHEN Oracle_Update like 'update' OR item_copy_from is not NULL
THEN 
    ''
    ELSE  ISNULL ( Item_Template , 'MAG Assembly' )
END         + '~' +
CASE WHEN Oracle_Update like 'update' OR item_copy_from is not NULL 
THEN 
    ''
    ELSE  ISNULL
```

Comment: No. You can't use an alias in the same `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nested query:

```
select 
SouceField_A  
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter'
+ SouceField_A
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter'
+ SourceField_B
+ 'DeliminiterCharacter' 
FROM (
SELECT CASE ... ) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used a derived table, where this table is defined in the FROM clause. I've given the long code the column aliases `SourceField_A` and `SourceField_B`.  The derived table is aliased `dT`.  For clarity, the SELECT clause can use the alias in front of the column name.  For example, `dT.SourceField_A`

```
SELECT dT.SourceField_A
     + 'DeliminiterCharacter'
     + dT.SourceField_A
     + 'DeliminiterCharacter'
     + dT.SourceField_B
     + 'DeliminiterCharacter'

  FROM (
         ISNULL ( Oracle_Update , 'create' )  + '~' +
         @Email + '~' +
         @ItemNo + '~' +
         ''  + '~' +
         'D'  + '~' +
         ISNULL ( Item_Desc_DE , '' )  + '~' +
         REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL ( Item_Specification_DE , '' ), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR   (10), ' $#') + '~' +    
         ISNULL ( Item_Copy_From, '' ) + '~' +
         -- master template
          CASE WHEN Oracle_Update like 'update' OR item_copy_from is not NULL
          THEN 
            ''
          ELSE  ISNULL ( Item_Template , 'MAG Assembly' )
          END         + '~' +
          CASE WHEN Oracle_Update like 'update' OR item_copy_from is not NULL 
          THEN 
            ''
            ELSE  ISNULL 
           ... 
            AS SourceField_A

           ,... 
            AS SourceField_B
       ) AS dT
```